# ¿Como puedo habilitar un boton si en otro componente formulario le dieron submit? Angular 2, Material

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Hola chicos tengo dos componentes en angular 2 uno componente A donde tengo un botón y componente B donde tengo un formulario de registro, ahora como puedo validar el botón en el componente A para que aparezca cuando el submit de componente B ha sido exitoso y mantenerlo oculto si el submit no ha sido ejecutado?
Nota pero son dos componentes diferentes A y B

codigo del componente A .html

```
<div>
<button md-mini-fab color="warn" class="flotante mr-1" ><md-icon>add</md-icon></button>
</div>
```

codigo del componente B .html

```
<form class="pt-1" [formGroup]="altaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
            <div class="pb-1">
                <md-select placeholder="Seleccione un producto" id="id" formControlName="id" class="full-width" [(ngModel)]="new.idproducto">
                    <md-option *ngFor="let med of tools" [value]='med.id'>{{med.tool}}</md-option>
                </md-select>
              </div>
            <div class="pb-1">
                <md-form-field class="full-width">
                    <input mdInput type="number" min="1" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad (Minimo: 1)" formControlName="cantidad">
                </md-form-field>

            <div class="card-title-text center">
                <div class="">
                    <span fxFlex></span>
                    <button type="submit" md-mini-fab class="mat-primary" [disabled]="altaForm.invalid"><md-icon>send</md-icon></button>
                </div>
            </div></form>
```

y en el .ts del componente B

```
onSubmit(event: Event) {
     event.preventDefault();

    this._addService.newTool(this.new.id, this.new.cantidad).subscribe(
       (data) => {
         console.log('agregado');

      },
      err => {
          console.error(err);

       },
       () => {

       }
     );
    }
```

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]** para que aprendas como formular correctamente una pregunta, debes colocar el código que estás usando y lo que has intentado además de los errores que te ha arrojado el sistema, saludos !

Comment: El componente B esta dentro del componente A o ambos componentes se encuentran dentro del app.component?

Comment: los dos componentes estan en el mismo nivel que el app.ts